# Jenkins cli connection timed out

Tags: jenkins, nmap, jenkins-cli

I am trying to access Jenkins from another server than the one it's installed one. When I try to run

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://remote:port/jenkins help
```

I have, after a few dozens of seconds, a `java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to connect to http://remote:port/jenkins/` error.

Pinging the remote works, and running `nmap -p port remote` gives me

```
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-28 11:51 CEST
Nmap scan report for [remote]
Host is up (0.00047s latency).
PORT       STATE    SERVICE
[port]/tcp filtered m2mservices

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.27 seconds
```

Is the problem related to the `filtered` state?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not a connection timeout - consider renaming the Question topic so it wouldn't be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. You need to check your firewall settings.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out on Monday.

Comment: The problem does not come from the firewall settings. When I run `iptables -L -n`, I actually have no firewall rules.

Comment: Did you check the settings on the _server_ side also?

Comment: Mmm you might be right. The server on which I try to run jenkins cli does have some firewall configuration. The server on which Jenkins is located does not.